# How do I add a custom Form element helper to Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement's typemap?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I'm trying to add a 'DivElement' (just a blank div) as an exercise, to a ZF2 form.

I've created `Application\Form\Element\DivElement`

```
namespace Application\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element;

class DivElement extends Element {

    protected $attributes = array(
        'type' => 'div'
    );

 }
```

To accompany it, I've created `Application\Form\View\Helper\DivElementHelper.php`

```
namespace Application\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class DivElementHelper extends AbstractHelper
{

    public function __invoke(ElementInterface $element = null)
    {
        if (!$element)
            return $this;

        return $this->render($element);
    }

    /**
     * @see \Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper::render()
     * @param ElementInterface $oElement
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(ElementInterface $oElement)
    {
        return "<div class='" . $oElement->getAttribute('class')  . "'></div>";
    }
}
```

I also added an invokable to my module.config.php as:

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'formdiv' => DivElementHelper::class,
    ],
],
```

The last part of the puzzle, seems to be that of getting my formdiv helper into `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement`'s `protected $typeMap` array.  I can't seem to figure what config adds a mapping of:

**'div' => 'formdiv'**

to the former.  There's clearly an addType method in there, so someone has thought of it!  How do I get my darned class in there?

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZF2 have confirmed there is no configuration-way to achieve this right now.  Looks like the Module-way in onBootstrap is the only route:

`php
$services->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('formelement')->addType( 'div', 'formdiv' );`